# Which pedals do they use?

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal

Is there anybody has any idea which pedals might be used for [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASrS7GrhBH0&feature=youtu.be)? I looked up on comments but there is no answer at all.

Comment: There are several different effects used at different times. They may not even be pedals. Can you be more specific.

Comment: Actually I am interested in vintage sound

Comment: You might well be, but it doesn't help us answering the question!

Comment: Then it means I do not have proper knowledge to properly tell which sound exactly I am looking for.

Comment: You can start by explaining which part. In that intro, it seemed like a cheap vintage guitar which gets a very sitar-like sound because of fret buzz, with maybe a little chorus but not much. You can link to a specific starting time with the YouTube video sharing mechanism.

Comment: Dear Dave Jacoby thank you for your suggestions. I was exactly looking for that part, for that vintage sound at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this video](https://youtu.be/iPp2fdHMxTM?t=342) seems like the sound is coming from an Fender Hot Rod Deluxe, which is a tube amplifier. This is what is making this kind of "vintage" sound.

From [here](https://brightonsource.co.uk/previews/mauskovic-dance-band-los-bitchos-preview/) you can have a glance on the pedals, seems there is at least a Big Muff Pi and a Boss Overdrive plus maybe a Mooer Octave and an unidentified pedal… It is likely that not all of them (maybe none) are used in the song you linked ;).

Hope it helps!